No ver agua en el mar
My Valencian friend gave me a new phrase. She said: "No veo agua en el mar".
She said: "No veo las oportunidades de trabajo en mi ciudad, no veo agua en el mar".
I tried searching for this phrase online but I can't find it anywhere. Maybe it is from the Valencian dialect.
There is nothing in the RAE or Spanishdict or anywhere I look.
I know there is "echar agua al mar" which means putting effort or time into something that doesn't need it or deserve it. That is different.
I want to know if it is a widely accepted phrase to use. I would like to use it in an essay about appreciating our own culture and that we don't appreciate what we have ourselves. Would it be good here?
I know there are alternatives e.g. "echar margaritas al cerdo" (if people don't appreciate something) and "hacerse la miel para la boca del asno" which are like "casting pearls amongst swine".

In writing, if it works and is grammatical, you can use it, don't you think?

Me da la sensación de que es una extraña adaptación del refrán:

No trobar aigua a mar

que en castellano se traduce como

No encontrar agua en el mar

Parece que en este programa de radio (en catalán) explican su significado:

No trobar aigua a mar (al mar, a la mar, en la mar)": no veure una
cosa que es té al davant, com qui no sap veure l'aigua quan és al
costat del mar.

Que según google translator - yo no sé hablar catalán -, se traduce como

No encontrar agua en mar (en el mar, en el mar, en el mar)": no ver algo que se tiene delante, como quien no sabe ver el agua cuando está junto al mar.

En este tweet también lo explican

(1) Expressions i frases fetes catalanes:  No trobar aigua a mar/
Aigua a mar no trobaries. Significat: Ésser poc eixerit, especialment
per cercar quelcom. No trobar allò que és fàcil de trobar. No veure
allò que tens al davant.
(2) Expressions sinònimes: Si fos un gos, et mossegaria;Tenir pa a
l'ull; Tenir palla a l'ull; No veure-hi més enllà del nas; No veure un
bou a tres passes. Exemple: Guaita'l! És aquí a dins! És ben bé que no
trobaries aigua a mar!

Que traducido al castellano usando la misma herramienta sería

(1) Expresiones y frases hechas catalanas: No encontrar agua en mar/
Agua en mar no encontrarías. Significado: Ser poco vivaracho,
especialmente para buscar algo. No encontrar lo que es fácil de
encontrar. No ver lo que tienes delante.
(2) Expresiones sinónimas: Si fuera un perro, te mordería;Tener pan en
el ojo; Tener paja en el ojo; No ver más allá de la nariz; No ver un
buey a tres pasos. Ejemplo: ¡Gaítalo! ¡Está aquí dentro! ¡Es que no
encontrarías agua en mar!


En resumen, parece que la frase original es "no trobar aigua a mar" que significa en castellano "no ser capaz de ver algo que es evidente por falta de interés o capacidad". Parece que tu amiga ha mezclado el refrán con su significado al traducirlo al castellano y ha cambiado "encontrar" por "ver": no ver agua en el mar, queriendo decir que puede que haya muchos trabajos disponibles en Valencia, pero ella no es capaz de encontrar/ver ninguno.

una explicacion muy buena ,RubioRic. No hablo catalán ,por eso , tus traducciones me ayudan. entonces, parece usted una buena idea usar  '' no encuentro agua en el mar'' en mi redaccion hablando de lo bueno de nuestra propia cultura?

Ten en cuenta que yo tampoco sé catalán. Si tu redacción es en castellano, yo no la usaría, su significado no está claro para un castellano-hablante en mi opinión

Sí,creo que tiene usted razón. Tenía estas dudas y es por lo que pregunté. Probablemente,sería mejor usar ''nuestra cultura es oro en pano'' o ''no deberíamos echar margaritas a los cerdos ,hacerse miel para la boca del asno o echar agua al mar'' para describir lo que nuestra cultura tiene que ofrecer y no desperdiciar nuestros esfuerzos en alguien que no lo valora.

El refrán funciona perfectamente en español.  ¿ Porqué traducir algo que es tan bonito y que se entiende sin problemas?

@Lambie Para mí no funciona porque no lo interpreto como un refrán al leerlo. Tiene sentido una vez sabes eso, que es un refrán.

La cuestión es si una metáfora funciona, funciona. No veo ningún inconveniente. No todo en la vida "se ha dicho" o ya fue dicho. Y para un escritor puede ser muy útil.

@Bluelion7 Yo veo muy forzado el uso de esos refranes en tu contexto. Y me estoy perdiendo un poco con lo que quieres expresar. ¿Somos nosotros lo que no apreciamos lo que nuestra cultura y nuestra tierra nos ofrece? ¿Hay gente (autóctona o extranjera) que no aprecia esas bondades y debemos ignorar sus críticas?

El título de mi redaccion es ''Hay que celebrar nuestra cultura''.Tengo la idea de hablar de que no apreciamos nuestra propia cultura y estamos mirando hacia otras(que no es mala cosa en si misma). Sí, son los nativos que no aprecian su cultura. Puede que sean forzados y anquilosados pero no voy a usar todos a la vez o tal vez solo uno.

@Lambie. Sí,creo que es bonito y que funciona.  Al mismo tiempo creo que sería mejor para mi usarlo con mi amiga y no en mi redacción de castellano ya que  es oficial. Mejor prevenir que lamentar,supongo.

La primera frase podemos decir que deriva de una expresión que sí está en el diccionario con coronita:

arrojarse a la mar

loc. verb. Aventurarse a un grave riesgo.


Por mi parte, puedo decir jamás escuché la expresión. En la Argentina, a eso le llamamos piletazo, o bien tirar un piletazo, de donde es completamente lógico decir cosas como no veo agua en la pileta.
Ahora bien, tus otras dos frases también refieren a evaluaciones y valoraciones pero no son equivalentes ya que el no ver agua en la pileta hace referencia a un riesgo que se toma para conseguir lo que no se tiene. Mientras que no le des margaritas al cerdo, o no está hecha la miel para la boca del asno se usa un un sentido más peyorativo, es decir que los gronchos y todas las personas de mal gusto no saben valorar todo lo bueno que se les presenta.
Entiendo igualmente que en tu caso ambos sentidos van de la mano, ya que tu amiga no se atreve a arriesgar para conseguir lo que no tiene porque no sabe valorar lo que sí tiene.

En España también usamos una expresión parecida a la que apuntas de "tirar un piletazo", que es equivalente "tirarse a la piscina" que significa arriesgarse si tener en cuanta posibles efectos negativos. Pileta y piscina son sinónimos teniendo en cuenta el elemento que identifican en Argentina y España, respectivamente. En cualquier caso creo que ninguna de las dos tiene que ver con la expresión catalana que indica el OP.
